# Default value in function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

In PHP we can define the argument value for the functions if it's not set(called), so for example:

```
<?php
    function blah($arg = false){
        var_dump($arg);
    }
?>
```

In the above example if we call the function like:

```
<?php
    blah();
    // ==> out put will be: false;
    blah(true);
    // ==> out put will be: true;
?>
```

So we can define a value for the arguments if they are not settled while we call the function, how this could be achieved in javascript functions?

I have it exactly like PHP:

```
<script>
    function blah(arg = false){
        //...
    }
</script>
```

The above code works just fine in Mozilla Firefox, but in Chrome, the function is not working and gets fixed when I remove `= false` in the parenthesis, Chrome developer tools says:

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token =

Comment: [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters) are a part of ECMAScript 6. At the moment, [only FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) supports some of newcoming features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cleanest pattern for implementing default arguments in javascript IMO.

```
function (arg) {
  arg = arg || 'defaultVale';
}
```

However this can fail if you expect the value of arg to be some falsy value, e.g `0, false, NaN, null` using it is not really recommended.

This version protects against this case by explicitly comparing with undefined.

```
function (arg) {
  arg = arg === undefined ? 'defaultVale' : arg;
  // As T.J Crowder pointer out if not in strict mode or if the code will run 
  // in an IFrame use typeof arg === "undefined" instead of directly
  // comparing with undefined
}
```

Another nice pattern is using objects for arguments instead. This has two benefits

1. Order of arguments is not important
2. It's easy to implement default arguments

**Code**

```
var defaults = {
  arg1: 10,
  arg2: 20
};

var f = function (args) {
  args = jQuery.extend(true, args, defaults); //jQuery
  args = _.defaults(args, defaults); // Underscore
};

f({
  a: 25 //Use a non default value
});
```

Comment: Note that `undefined` can be shadowed, and the `undefined` in one window is not `===` the `undefined` in another window, so if you're writing any code that may be used in a multi-frame environment, that check is a bad idea. `typeof arg === "undefined"` is reliable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Very nice point T.J, but this is not possible in strict mode. And he should be using "strict mode" in any case.

Comment: @ Hugo: Strict mode has no effect on the multi-window (frames) situation.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in Javascript.
Try this `Conditional Operator` statement instead:

```
<script>
    function blah(arg){
       arg = typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : 'someValue';
    }
</script>
```

Where 'someValue' is the default value that the `arg` variable will get when there are no arguments passed to the `blah()` function.

Comment: I think that arg !== undefined will do as well

Comment: @xpy: Be careful doing that. `undefined` in one window is not `===` `undefined` in another window, so if you're doing a library or any kind of app with multiple windows (frames)...

Comment: @xpy And in old browsers `undefined` can be reassigned I believe.

Comment: @thefourtheye: And can be shadowed even in new browsers, in loose mode. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there is no default parameter.
Just write the code like:

```
function test(arg) {
    if(arg) {
        // do something as arg is defined.
    } else {
        // do something as arg is undefined.
    }
}

test(true); // arg is defined
test();  // arg is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

In Js you can't have default values for parameters. You can check if the data is of a known type with `typeof` operator:

```
function blah(arg)
{
    if (typeof arg === 'undefined')
    {
        arg = false;
    }
}
```

or setting his value in a short-circuit way

```
function blah(arg)
{
    arg = arg || false;
}
```

For example in coffeescript you can set it by using

`blah = (arg = "mydefaultvalue") ->`

that is translated into

```
blah = function(arg)
{
    if (arg == null) 
    {
        arg = "mydefaultvalue";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple variation

```
function defaulter(p1) {
    p1 = p1 || "default";
}
```

Comment: This should **NOT** be recommended. If the user explicitly passes falsy value for `p1`, it will still use `default`

Comment: Or `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `false`... There's a place for this, but only if the non-default value won't be falsey. Without a clear description, it's not useful to say "just do this."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was just changing it to falsy values :)

Comment: Yes, I could have added a comment regarding falsy values.